# Unable to connect Node.js app to React.js app while deploying on Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a MERN app (React.js as client & Node.js as server) on Azure. I have created A Cosmos DB Account and database (MongoDB) and connected my Node.js app to that database.

I am unable to create communication between my Node.js & React.js apps.

I have created **build of my React.js app and pasted in Node.js app** and deploying Node.js app.

I am getting issue

> 'cannot GET/'

I also tried deploying the app manually by pasting whole React.js app ino Node.js app in structure below--

```
|- node-app
   |- client
       |- react-app
|- node-app rest files...
```

I don't know how to get env variables on production

**My app.js is below--**

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('./config/database.config');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/build/index.html'));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**My database config file is below--**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONN,
  {
    auth :{user : process.env.DB_USER, password : process.env.DB_PW},
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
    .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: You first need to set your environment variables in your azure app from it's web app settings

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I think your issue was caused by your code `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));` to serve the static files of React client built by `npm run build`.

On Azure, there is a difference for the variable __dirname between local and Azure. On local, the value of __dirname variable is always the full path name where you start up a node process, such as print __dirname will return D:\home if run node in CMD at D:\home. But on Azure, you will see the __dirname value in any path which be . if you try to run the command node -e "const path = require('path'); console.log(__dirname);" in the Kudu console, as the figure below.

[image]

Therefore, the `path.join(__dirname, 'build')` value is always `build` which not be related to the current path of node started up by IIS. So to fix it, please use an absolute path like `D:\home\site\wwwroot` instead of `__dirname` variable in `path.join` method or just directly use `D:\home\site\wwwroot\build` in `express.static` method.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @ParvezSiddiqi Any update? If my answer is helpful for you, could you mark it?